# How to debug a BIRT report integrated with Spring

Tags: debugging, spring-mvc, birt

I already have integrated Spring and BIRT using this http://spring.io/blog/2012/01/30/spring-framework-birt.

But now, I want to debug my reports using the BIRT designer, but this is not possible because the designer is not running in the same VM/classloader.

After some research, I found a possible solution (http://birtworld.blogspot.com.br/2009/11/accessing-spring-beans-from-birt.html), in resume this soluction creates a RMI for the spring bean for acccess it from BIRT report via HTTP request.

The problem is, that the domain DTOs isn't visible to the BIRT Designer (again!!!).

There are any solution to my problem?

How can I debug a report integrated with spring using BIRT Designer?